# Using snap draggable only on one side of the element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to make that draggable elements could stick to only one side of another element? I need to make four elements could stick with four different sides to the fifth element, but each with only one hand.
In other words  may stick just to the left,  only the top and so on.

Comment: Create a fiddle of what have you tried so far

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YvJhE/313/
My last idea was to create additional elements on the edges of the fifth, but as you can see, it also failed

Comment: I saw you made it. Very nice thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<style>
#draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ axis: "y" });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
<p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

hope this would help you